# Is there a default variable with user's input as value in Dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

For example, if I want to verify if there is a keyword in the user's utterance but I dont want to train an intent nor use form params, just the fullfilment's condition field such as:

> $user.input : "keyword"

Translated has... does the user's utterance contain the word "keyword"?

Answer (score 1):

Specifically for [Conditions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/condition), there are no such default parameters or variables that will contain the user’s input query as a value. Conditional triggers are explicitly only for use with the parameters: $intent, $page, and $session. As mentioned in the conditions reference, the parameters that can be set are listed under the [parameters](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/parameter) guide.

If you were asking for a parameter/variable that could be used with Conditions that contained a specific keyword within the query, such a thing would not be possible unless an intent, form or session parameter had been defined or set.

Though you specified you wanted to just use the Conditions Fulfillment, the following are 2 possible solutions:

A) A simple solution is available that requires only a [Webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/webhook) that will be able to handle the verification. Have your Webhook be ready to parse the incoming JSON [WebhookRequest](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.dialogflow.cx.v3beta1#webhookrequest), seeking either a *text*, *trigger_intent*, *transcript*, or *trigger_event* field, depending on the user’s query input method. For example, if the user input via text, your webhook should look for the ‘text’ field within the Webhook request, check if the keyword is there, and handle it correctly.

B) A different workaround utilizing the API that will allow you access to a copy of the User’s input query is utilizing the [API & Client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference) directly in your implementation. For example, you may use the REST API as follows:

1. Send user queries to Dialogflow via [DetectIntent](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations.agents.sessions/detectIntent)
2. Upon return they will contain a [DetectIntentResponse](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/DetectIntentResponse), which contains a [QueryResult](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3/QueryResult)
3. Within QueryResult:
   If natural language speech
   audio was provided as an input, a text string of the transcripted
   audio will be stored in “transcript”.
   If natural language text was
   provided instead, a copy of the text will be stored in “text”

Answer (score 1):

There's no default parameter, but you could easily add your own.

You could add a parameter with entity type `@sys.any`, which can capture the user input and put the value into the variable.

[image]

Then you will be able to use a Route to check if the user_input meets your condition

[image]